# Excel Index Match when Index data isn't a 100% match

Tags: excel

I've been trying to figure this out for days now and can't seem to get a 100% working solutions.

Issue:

I have 3 different data lists. See below.

List A:

```
Product                           Product_price
Apple iPhone 6s 64 GB Space Gray    799
Apple iPhone 6s 64 GB Rose Gold     799
Apple iPhone 6s 64 GB Zilver        795
Apple iPhone 6s 64 GB Goud          829
```

List B:

```
Product                           Product_price  
APPLE IPHONE 6S 64GB SILVER         795
APPLE IPHONE 6S 64GB ROSE GOLD      799
APPLE IPHONE 6S 64GB SPACE GREY     799
APPLE IPHONE 6S 64GB GOLD           829
```

List C:

```
item_2_name                                    item_3_price
APPLE iPhone 6s 64 GB Space Gray (MKQN2ZD/A)       799
APPLE iPhone 6s 64 GB Silver (MKQP2ZD/A)           795
APPLE iPhone 6s 64 GB Gold (MKQQ2ZD/A)             829
APPLE iPhone 6s 64 GB Rose Gold (MKQR2ZD/A)        799
```

What I want to achieve is that List B and List C match with List A.
I've been playing around with Index Match with wildcards for example `=INDEX(Coolblue!B:B;MATCH("*"&Blad1!A:A&"*";Coolblue!A:A;0))`

To make is easiers, the product names are in column A and the prices in B

Is there any other method to make this work?

Comment: Have you tried the [Excel Fuzzy Lookup add-in](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011)? (free from MS).  I have not tried it in my Excel 2016 because of some reported issues, but it might be able to do what you want.  Be sure to read the tutorials and other help info on the 'net to be able to use it.

Comment: I didn't try Excel Fuzzy Lookup add-in. I'm on 2016 aswel

Comment: Well, maybe you won't run into the problem another has reported.  It shouldn't hurt to try.

Comment: I'm on it. Let you know later how I got on with it. Any other "solutions" are stil welcome.

Comment: Yes, please let me know.  Some have had problems, some have not.

Answer (score 0):

As Ron suggested I've tried Excel Fuzzy Lookup add-in and this in Excel 2016.
First I must mention that I didn't encounter any issues as Ron mentioned that other users had. It did the job. Thank you Ron

Below is the out put that I got after the Fuzzy Match.

[image]